# More efficient way to make a cooldown timer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner and am learning to use C# and Unity. Recently, I wrote a code about using skills, and it must have a cooldown time. So, my code looked like this:

```
public float projectileCooldown = 3f;
public float currentTime, lastKeyInputTime = 0f;

void Update()
{
    currentTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (currentTime - lastKeyInputTime >= projectileCooldown)
        {
            SpawnProjectile();
            lastKeyInputTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        }
    }
}
```

I looked up the documentation and still have no idea what I should do. Wondering if there's a more efficient way to use the variable.

**When the game has passed for a long time. The value inside would be really large. Is there an alternative?**
Thanks!

Comment: Make a class that encapsulate all of the cooldown functionality and name it `Cooldown`. Then in your code just do `if (cooldown.IsReady)`. This is my implementation https://pastebin.com/NjqSUjME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual implementation for a cooldown is a float that gets counted down to 0. When it's below or equal to 0, the cooldown is over. Usually, you use a second float to store the total time for the cooldown.

You can encapsulate that in a class, but it's optional.

```
float totalCooldownTime = 3.0f;
float currentCooldownTime = 0.0f;

void Update()
{
    if (currentCooldownTime >= 0.0f)
    {
        currentCooldownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

When using your ability, you would simply check against the currentCooldownTime and if it's below or equal to 0 you assign the total time to it.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && currentCooldownTime <= 0.0f)
{
    // Do your action here

    currentCooldownTime = totalCooldownTime;
}
```

---

**Why is this better than using a Coroutine?**

The good thing about this solution is: The check against 0 is very cheap. There is no need to have a boolean to check against when you can just check against a float that also contains the remaining time.

A valid solution would be to add properties like

```
public bool IsCooldownActive => currentCooldownTime > 0.0f;
```

that can be used everywhere without introducing a new value.

Also, you may want to visualize the cooldown. To get the time in seconds you want to display, you just do the following

```
public int RemainingCooldownSeconds => Mathf.FloorToInt(currentCooldownTime);
```

and if you want the ratio between current and total (maybe you want to show a progress bar!) you'd just divide by the total (if it's above 0)

```
public float CooldownPercentage => Mathf.Approximately(totalCooldownTime, 0.0f) ? 0.0f : currentCooldownTime / totalCooldownTime;
```

Also, using a coroutine removes your ability to have influence over the speed. Maybe you want to partially clear the cooldown or speed it up halfway through? Maybe you want to be able to pause the game and have the cooldown paused as well? Maybe you want to debug or display the current percentage of the cooldown for balancing reasons? There are a lot of factors that make this solution superior to using a Coroutine.

Comment: Fair play, great answer. Learned sth too:)

Answer (score -1):

[Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) can be of help for you I think:)

1. Introduce a `bool`, let's name it `cooledDown` which indicates whether player can shoot or not (cooldown has passed or not)
2. Call a coroutine whenever a shot was fired. This basically is your cooldown. While the coroutine is running, the player cannot shoot. This can be achieved by setting the introduced `cooledDown` boolean to `false` and checking for it in the `Update` as well
3. At the end of the coroutine, set the `cooledDown` back to true, thereby unlocking the next shot. In other words, cooldown has passed.

See the following implementation for the coroutine:

```
IEnumerator CooldownRoutine(int cooldownInSeconds)
{
    // Block any attempt to shoot
    cooledDown = false;

    // Wait for specified number of seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldownInSeconds);

    // Cooldown is over. Unlock shot
    cooledDown = true;
}
```

In your `Update` function you would then check for completed cooldown as well as key-down event:

```
void Update()
{
    if (cooledDown == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        SpawnProjectile();

        // Call cooldown routine
        StartCoroutine(CooldownRoutine(desiredCooldownInSeconds));
    }
}
```